# How to publish an ASPNET Website automatically to a Linux VPS?

Tags: asp.net-core, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, asp.net-core-3.0

Hello I want to build a build pipeline for a website. Whenever someone pushs something to git I want to trigger an action which builds the website (got that working with teamcity) and automatically deploys it to a staging server (docker container on some linux vps)

I could upload the artifact per ftp and check the ftp folder on the server per cronjob or something similar. But there has to be a better solution. Can you help me with that? Thank you.

TLDR I want to build, deploy and restart a website on every push to git.

Everything is selfhosted. No AWS, Azure or similar

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? In the release pipeline you copy the file(s) to the server and run a shell command to extract an restart.

Comment: There can be too many options (Git based or others), but Stack Overflow is not a place to judge the options, or give you recommendations.